# Non-breaking space character in Markdown for Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

In telegram bot it's possible to hide a link in html with non breaking space:

```
<a href="google.com">&#160;</a>
```

But for some reason i have to use markdown. Is there a kind of non-breakable space i could use in Markdown?

```
[NO TEXT](google.com)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it now, it was a bug for zero-width space `​` and RTL (Right-to-Left) control char, but it can't send along now.